# Canvas - new shapes get wrong colors

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was trying to make a small game in which there are a few shapes with different colors, but I ran into a problem which I have managed to boil down to this js code:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight

const context = canvas.getContext("2d")

context.beginPath()
context.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 30, 0, 2*Math.PI, false)
context.fillStyle = 'blue'
context.fill()

context.beginPath()
context.fillRect(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 100, 30)
context.fillStyle = 'green'
context.fill()
```

I create a blue circle and then I want to create a green rectangle, but the rectangle for whatever reason takes the color from the circle and is drawn as blue.

What could be the reason for not changing the fillStyle as I want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order of the calls. First set the `fillStyle` and than the `fillRect`

See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/dw5u9etk/

```
const context = canvas.getContext("2d")

context.beginPath()
context.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 30, 0, 2*Math.PI, false)
context.fillStyle = 'blue'
context.fill()

context.beginPath()
context.fillStyle = 'green' // I only moved this line up
context.fillRect(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 100, 30)
context.fill()
```

Comment: I see, I thought that the context color would clear out after filling, although it obviously is not the case. Thank you for clarifying, I'm going to mark it as the answer when it becomes possible.

Answer (score 0):

`fillRect()` draws a new `rect` **outside** of the context's subpath and fills it directly.

When you call the last `fill()` the context's subpath is empty.

You could replace this method with `rect()` instead,

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d")

context.beginPath()
context.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 30, 0, 2*Math.PI, false)
context.fillStyle = 'blue'
context.fill()

context.beginPath()
context.rect(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 100, 30)
context.fillStyle = 'green'
context.fill()
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

or you could remove the `beginPath()` + `fill()` calls if you move the `fillStyle` assignment before the call to `fillRect()`:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d")

context.beginPath()
context.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 30, 0, 2*Math.PI, false)
context.fillStyle = 'blue'
context.fill()

context.fillStyle = 'green'
context.fillRect(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 100, 30)
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```